# Navigation Bar Expands When isTranslucent = False (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

I have a table view with a search bar. But, when I click the search bar it seems that the Navigation Bar expands and creates a blank white space beneath it. However, this only occurs when `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false` but when I comment this line, the white space never appears. Also, the white bar appears only when I press the search bar. Here are some pictures for reference:

1. This is when I don't press the search bar.
2. Then when I press the search bar a white space appears under it.
3. And then when I cancel out of the search bar the white space is between the navigation bar and the search bar.

[image: This is when I don't press the search bar.]

[image: Then when I press the search bar a white space appears under it.]

[image: And then when I cancel out of the search bar the white space is between the navigation bar and the search bar.]

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in `viewDidLoad`:

```
 self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

Comment: I added that line, but it still didn't fix the problem.